# Cloning from a particular commit SHA using git2 Rust

Tags: rust

I am trying to clone a repository from Github through Rust. Does the git2 crate in Rust support pulling from a particular commit SHA?

Comment: Will `Command::new("git clone").arg("...").status()` etc. work for you?

Comment: Is cloning from a particular commit hash supported with normal git? I don't think so. Iirc, all you can do is create a new empty repo, add a remote, and then fetch by refspec.

Answer (score 1):

After you have cloned the repository, you can checkout the tree and set the head to the corresponding commit.

```
use git2::{Object, Oid, Repository};

fn main() {
    let path = "/local/path/to/repo";
    let repo = "https://github.com/.../...";
    let commit = "77c8d299a614314461a7338757cc4ef9ec62ed31";

    Repository::clone(repo, path).unwrap();
    let repo: Repository = Repository::open(path).unwrap();
    let obj: Object = repo.find_commit(Oid::from_str(commit).unwrap()).unwrap().into_object();
    repo.checkout_tree(&obj, None).unwrap();
    repo.set_head_detached(obj.id()).unwrap();
}
```